# Is there a way to save animation on Textview as .gif file in android?

Tags: android, textview, gif, animated-gif

I have textview with different text animations I want to save them as .gif File in android storage, how is it possible to observe or download this animation effect?

[image: gif]

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Better to make custom git or lottie animation and load it

Comment: @MD do you have some idea how can I get it customly?

Comment: I don't have any idea but I recently tried Webflow in Android I came to this point